# Edit Specific Instance of Object

Tags: java

Say i let players create teams and creating a team calls a new instance of the team class which has an array list called members.

Now in the main class how would i add a player to a team after being invited? i have an addPlayer method in the team class that simply add them to the arraylist but what if there are currently multiple instances of the teams class(other players have created teams) how would it know which one to join?

I do have a variable in the Teams class for the teamLeader which gets set when creating the instance if that could help me edit a certain instance.

```
Team team = new Team(this, leader);
```

Any help is appreiciated

Comment: Can you post the source code from class `Team` and the part how you did call it?

Answer (score 1):

You need an identifier to uniquely distinguish each team and you can use that identifier to store the teams in a `Map`. Something like this:

```
Map<String,Team> teamMap = new HashMap<String,Team>();
```

Chose the key type as per your requirement, I chose String for an example

Comment: Yeah i thought i would need some kind of unique id for each team so i thought of the teamLeader variable being the identifier of the team, i just don't know how i would add a team based on the team leader such as. Add player to already made instance of Team where teamLeader = someplayer

Answer (score 0):

As per your design, You need to keep all teams in a list after creation.

```
ArrayList teamsList=new ArrayList ();
Team team = new Team(this, leader);
teamsList.add(team);
```

Then Loop through all teams in addPlayer method and then compare leader and then add a player to it. Something like this -

```
public void addPlayer (Player player,String leader){

for(int i=0; i<teamListSize;i++)

    Team tempTeam=teamsList.get(i);

    if(tempTeam.getLeader().equalsIgnoreCase(leader)){

        tempTeam.add(player);
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks good i will try this, i thought about storing all teams when created and looping over them but i wasn't sure if you can loop over all current instances of an object

Comment: So the teamsList array shouldnt be in the Team class right but you are accessing it from the appPlayer which is in the Team class? I'm creating the instance within my main class

Comment: If you make teamsList as an instance variable (outside main), it is accessible in addPlayer.