# Use Methods From Specific Object Instance

Tags: java, collections

Say i have a bit of code that creates an instance of an Apple with a given name

```
Apple apple = new Apple(playersName)
```

This line could be called by many players each having an instance of the Apple class where the name serves kind of as the ID

Now say in the Apple class there is an ArrayList which stores each players friends

```
ArrayList<String> applesFriends = new ArrayList<String>();
```

There will also be a getter/setter for updating and retrieving the friends, so if a specific player types a command /addfriend  to add a friend to his specific instances Array List how would i do that?

Example, Update instance of Apple WHERE name = currentPlayerTypingCommand

Comment: what exactly do you mean by a command?

Comment: I have a game that multiple people can play so multiple instances of the same object will be created by the players, i want to know how to update a specific players instance

Comment: please use only 1 question to get answers I think you posted similar Question before
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621663/edit-specific-instance-of-object

Comment: anyways
are you using some database?

Comment: No im not using a database

Answer (score 0):

If you are programming a game, there must be a game controller. This game will keep a list of the available `apples`. When someone asks to befriend another `apple`, the controller should search for the existence of the requested apple and add it to the friend list of the requesting `apple`.

A few ideas:

- Create a method `addFriend` inside `Apple`.
- Create an `equal` method inside `Apple`. Using it, your controller can use `indexOf` to search for the requested friend. In your case,
  the `equal` method would probably use only the name as the basis.
  This can also be used to prevent layers to use the same name.
- I would change applesFriends to be an `ArrayList<Apple>`. This way, if someone changes names, there would be no need to update them.
  Besides, you could easily implement a feature that also adds the
  requesting player to the friend list of the requested one (friendship
  relationships are reciprocal, aren't they?).